# Erdpy: Token issuance transaction fails with code: internal_issue

Tags: multiversx, erdpy

I try to make an ESDT token issuance transaction using the following Python code

```py
from erdpy.accounts import Account, Address
from erdpy.proxy import ElrondProxy
from erdpy.transactions import BunchOfTransactions
from erdpy.transactions import Transaction
from erdpy.wallet import signing


TOKEN_NAME = b"Cowdings"
TOKEN_SYMBOL = b"MOO"

DECIMALS = 18
SUPPLY = 1000 * 10**DECIMALS


def hex_string(s: str) -> str:
    assert type(s) == bytes, "Make sure everything is bytes data or utf-8 encoded"
    return hexlify(s).decode("ascii")


def hex_int(i: int) -> str:
    assert type(i) == int, "Make sure everything is bytes data or utf-8 encoded"
    return hex(i)[2:]


proxy = ElrondProxy("https://devnet-gateway.elrond.com")
sender = Account(pem_file="test-wallet.pem")
sender.sync_nonce(proxy)

tx = Transaction()
tx.nonce = sender.nonce
tx.value = str(0.05 * 10**18)  # 0.05 EGLD, as required for issuing a token according to the documentation
tx.sender = sender.address.bech32()
# System contract address to issue out the new token as per
# https://docs.elrond.com/developers/esdt-tokens/#issuance-of-fungible-esdt-tokens
tx.receiver = "erd1qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqpqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqzllls8a5w6u"
tx.gasPrice = 1000000000
tx.gasLimit = 50000
tx.data = f"issue" \
          f"@{hex_string(TOKEN_NAME)}" \
          f"@{hex_string(TOKEN_SYMBOL)}" \
          f"@{hex_int(SUPPLY)}" \
          f"@{hex_int(DECIMALS)}" 

tx.chainID = "D"  # For devnet https://devnet-gateway.elrond.com/network/config
tx.version = 1

tx.signature = signing.sign_transaction(tx, sender)
tx.send(proxy)
```

It fails with

```
ProxyRequestError: Proxy request error for url [https://devnet-gateway.elrond.com/transaction/send]: 
{
    'data': None, 
    'error': 'transaction generation failed: invalid value', 
    'code': 'internal_issue'
}
```

Comment: Full example here: https://github.com/miohtama/rosetta-chain/tree/master/chains/elrond/token

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use `str(0.05 * 10**18)` to get the string for the value.

However, this actually outputs the value in scientific notation, which isn't what the blockchain expects.

```
>>> str(0.05 * 10**18)
'5e+16'
```

Converting it to `int` first will force the correct output, so you can use `str(int(0.05 * 10**18))` instead :)

The full code therefore should look like this:

```py
from erdpy.accounts import Account, Address
from erdpy.proxy import ElrondProxy
from erdpy.transactions import BunchOfTransactions
from erdpy.transactions import Transaction
from erdpy.wallet import signing


TOKEN_NAME = b"Cowdings"
TOKEN_SYMBOL = b"MOO"

DECIMALS = 18
SUPPLY = 1000 * 10**DECIMALS


def hex_string(s: str) -> str:
    assert type(s) == bytes, "Make sure everything is bytes data or utf-8 encoded"
    return hexlify(s).decode("ascii")


def hex_int(i: int) -> str:
    assert type(i) == int, "Make sure everything is bytes data or utf-8 encoded"
    return hex(i)[2:]


proxy = ElrondProxy("https://devnet-gateway.elrond.com")
sender = Account(pem_file="test-wallet.pem")
sender.sync_nonce(proxy)

tx = Transaction()
tx.nonce = sender.nonce
tx.value = str(int(0.05 * 10**18))  # 0.05 EGLD, as required for issuing a token according to the documentation
tx.sender = sender.address.bech32()
# System contract address to issue out the new token as per
# https://docs.elrond.com/developers/esdt-tokens/#issuance-of-fungible-esdt-tokens
tx.receiver = "erd1qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqpqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqzllls8a5w6u"
tx.gasPrice = 1000000000
tx.gasLimit = 50000
tx.data = f"issue" \
          f"@{hex_string(TOKEN_NAME)}" \
          f"@{hex_string(TOKEN_SYMBOL)}" \
          f"@{hex_int(SUPPLY)}" \
          f"@{hex_int(DECIMALS)}" 

tx.chainID = "D"  # For devnet https://devnet-gateway.elrond.com/network/config
tx.version = 1

#New version for generating a signature:
tx.signature = sender.sign_transaction(tx)

#Old version which is now obsolete:
#tx.signature = signing.sign_transaction(tx, sender)

tx.send(proxy)
```

Comment: UPDATE 2021.12.26 : 

after library update this line doesnt works :

    tx.signature = signing.sign_transaction(tx, sender)


Use this instead :

    tx.signature = sender.sign_transaction(tx)

Comment: Updated my answer, including the new way to sign the transaction